# How to read POST (JSON RPC) data with boost::socket?

Tags: c++, boost, json-rpc

If I wrote an HTTP server that is listening to requests on some address, and it received a request from:

`curl --data-binary '{"method": "sum", "params": {"a":"3", "b":"4"}, "id":"0", "jsonrpc": "2.0"}' http://localhost:12345`

Now if my server owns a `boost::socket` to read from the port its listening to, how can it obtain the passed JSON object?

I find that `async_read_some()` doesn't read the bytes corresponding to the JSON object.

Comment: This question isn't clear. Are you asking how to parse JSON? Or are you asking why your call to `async_read_some()` doesn't work?

Comment: @SamMiller, I'm not asking how to parse serialized JSON strings. But I'm asking how I can read the JSON string in the first place. `async_read_some()` doesn't appear to fetch me those bytes at all.

Comment: edit your question and show some code, you haven't described how and why you're using `async_read_some()`. Similarly, `async_read_some()` reads a stream of bytes, not a JSON string, your application needs to handle the framing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of debugging, I found that `async_read_some()` does indeed fetch such JSON RPC information too (the entire HTTP request string basically).

The exact HTTP spec is followed as in here:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5

The entire HTTP request comes in a sequence of bytes, the JSON RPC part of which needs to be parsed with the help of a JSON parser.

As to what I was doing wrong, the buffer I passed to `async_read_some()` wasn't big enough and wasn't getting some parts of the HTTP request.